# pyQt5: Cannot connect QSpinBox::valueChanged(int)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qspinbox

I am new to Python and Qt. Currently, I am trying to build the UI for a larger application, but I am running into problems regarding signals and slots.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
import sys


class Ui_configDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_configDialog, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("configDialog")
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        self.resize(425, 380)

        row1 = DataRow(self)

        self.show()


class DataRow:
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 91, 30)

        self.text_fRep = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(dialog)
        self.text_fRep.setGeometry(rect.translated(100, 0))
        self.connect_signal()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def fRep_changed(self, value):
        print(value)

    def connect_signal(self):
        self.text_fRep.valueChanged.connect(self.fRep_changed)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Ui_configDialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I am trying to achieve is, that the slot fRep_changed is called whenever the value of the QSpinBox object is changed. But with this code I receive a compile error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect QSpinBox::valueChanged(int) to (null)::fRep_changed(int)
TypeError: connect() failed between valueChanged(int) and fRep_changed()
```

I cannot see, why I shouldn't be able to connect the signal to the slot.

I also removed the @pyqtSlot(int). The application starts, but nothing happens when the value is changed.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has 2 errors, the first one is that the slots are only implemented within the classes that inherit from `QObject`, so the easiest thing is for your class to inherit from `QObject`. The second you will see after making the previous change, it will happen that even if you change the value of `QSpinBox` will never be called to the slot, and this happens because the collector deletes the object of `row1` of the `DataRow` class, the solution is simple, you just have to make row a member of the class through self, ie change `row1` by `self.row1`

```
class Ui_configDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_configDialog, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("configDialog")
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        self.resize(425, 380)

        self.row1 = DataRow(self)

        self.show()


class DataRow(QObject):
    def __init__(self, dialog, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        rect = QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 91, 30)

        self.text_fRep = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(dialog)
        self.text_fRep.setGeometry(rect.translated(100, 0))
        self.connect_signal()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def fRep_changed(self, value):
        print(value)

    def connect_signal(self):
        self.text_fRep.valueChanged.connect(self.fRep_changed)
```